# How can I make a nested array in a way similar to numpy.zeros?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to make an array like this with javascript ?:

```
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)
```

With python I'd call `np.zeros((4, 2, 3), dtype = np.float32)`

Comment: Yes. It is. Have you tried? What problems did you face?

Comment: All numbers can be floats. You don't need to set a type in Javascript.

Comment: Are you worried about the float type?  Does it not just work with a regular array?  If you must have it typed (you usually don't) you can use a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) (or array of typed arrays).

Comment: passing type is not needed in Javascript. You can declare array like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing in javascript, but it's easy to write:

```js
function zeros([length, ...rest], type) {
    if (rest.length > 0)
        return Array.from({length}, _ => zeros(rest, type));

    if (!type)
        return Array(length).fill(0);

    return new type(length);
}

console.log(zeros([2, 5]))
console.log(zeros([4, 2, 3], Float32Array))
console.log(zeros([4, 2, 3], Uint8Array))
```

If no type is given, the innermost array will be a standard `Array` with `number` values, otherwise a typed array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have distinct types for Int and Float, it just has the type `number`.
Hence, you can use the following:

```js
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  arr[i] = [[], []];
  for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = [0, 0, 0];
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```